# Custom names to call applications

Tags: lubuntu

one of the things I love about linux is freedom. I am not forced to follow 100% of the 'rules' that a company or a programmer thought for the product in its origin. With that in mind, what I would like is to put simple names to my applications, instead of having to remember funny names like 'featherpad' for a text editor, 'okular' when I need to read a PDF file, 'qlipper' etc. you get my point. Also, I tend to try several applications before settling in my favorite for a given task so it is not easy to memorize all these crazy names. The thing is, I usually call these from "runner" application (Alt+F2 in my default setup). So when I need to open a calculator I need to remember the crazy name of the last calculator I installed (qalculate!).

So, it would be great if I could change the 'name' of an application, at least how my 'runner' (not sure if it is called like that) calls it. This way, I can just press Alt+F2 and write "calculator" and it will offer the application I chose to (in this case, 'qalculate!') and 'libreoffice calc' as well. By typing "text editor" I would see 'featherpad' and 'libreoffice writer' in the list. By typing "drawing" I would see 'inkscape' etc.

I understand runner searches for name of the application, that is why I see 'libreoffice calc' when I type "calc". But I don't see qalculator! because it does not include the 'calc' text I just entered. So, can I change something somewhere so 'runner' associates qalculator! with the text "calculator"? Then I would do the same for "text" as mentioned above, etc.

I'm using Lubuntu.
This is the output of lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:        18.10
Codename:       cosmic

Comment: Lubuntu 18.10 (in fact all 18.10 flavors & Ubuntu 18.10 itself) has reached EOL, so please `do-release-upgrade` asap.  https://lubuntu.me/cosmic-etc-eol/

Answer (score 3):

If you create a shortcut, and put it in a /bin directory (eg. ~/bin IF you have it in your $PATH, or /usr/local/bin/) you can then use your ALT+F2 *Application Finder* to run.

For example

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/featherpad /usr/local/bin/blah`

creates a shortcut called `blah` in /usr/local/bin/ directory (which is in the default path, /home/user/bin/ may be a better choice), then typing ALT+F2 to open *Application Finder* and typing 'blah' opens Featherpad.

Note: I used `whereis featherpad` to work out where that program was located.

Also please release-upgrade ASAP as Lubuntu 18.10, and all flavors of 18.10 are now EOL. Please refer to https://lubuntu.me/cosmic-etc-eol/ , or refer to https://manual.lubuntu.me/D/upgrading.html if you need help release-upgrading to 19.04.

I also used `blah` as example only, but don't use names already reserved for applications (even if not installed) to avoid creating problems for yourself *down the road*.  I personally aren't sure this is a good idea, but it achieves your aim.

Comment: Your warning about down the road potential problems triggered some helpful reflection. Thus I decided I will not rename to common names as "text editor" but to a string only myself uses. For example when I press Alt-F2 to call the application finder, my finger rests very comfortably close to the key "|". So I will use "||" and then the keyword, for example instead of "Libreoffice Writer" I will rename to "||text". I hope by doing this I get rid of 99% of potential problems.